# How to MoveTowards on the x only?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,
                        targetTransform.position, Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);
```

I want to move the transform towards a target but only on the x.

Comment: Create a temporary vector with target.Y = transform.Y and target.Z = transform.Z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Mathf.MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.MoveTowards.html) on the `x`:

```
Vector3 newPos = transform.position;
newPos.x = Mathf.MoveTowards(newPos.x, targetTransform.position.x, 
        Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);
transform.position = newPos;
```